# How can I retrieve properties that have price for each date between the given dates?

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables [Agency_DailyPrices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1Una.png) and [Agency_DailyDiscounts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cQwQ.png).

Here is my query:

```
DECLARE @checkIn DATE = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE);
DECLARE @checkOut DATE = DATEADD(DAY, 6, @checkIn);
DECLARE @currency_id INT = 3;

SELECT AP.date_, AP.property_id, price, discountPercent, 
CASE WHEN discountPercent > 0 THEN (price * discountPercent/100) ELSE 0 END AS discountAmount
FROM Agency_DailyPrices AP
LEFT JOIN Agency_DailyDiscounts AD ON AD.date_= AP.date_ AND AD.property_id = AP.property_id
WHERE (AP.date_ BETWEEN @checkIn AND @checkOut) AND
        currency_id = @currency_id
ORDER BY AP.property_id;
```

And here is the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVrXs.png).

I want to filter the records with property_id = 62 as there is no price for 2021-06-01.
In the other words. How can I retrieve properties that have price for each date between the given dates?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Links to images of data don't help us help you. Post the sample data as DDL and DML statements; at at worst well formatted tabular `text`. Perhaps, however, what you are after here is an `EXISTS`?

Answer (score 0):

As temporary solution I counted the number of days between the given dates (in this case 7). And I return the the records if the total number of rows per property was equal to 7.